# Android work multitouch button

Tags: android, button, multi-touch, sample

Hi i want to create 2 Button and i want to multitouch ??

i tryed to do but no example in internet..

So if you got one can you share or can you give me opinion ??
my code is this but not support multitouch

```
 package multi.touch;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
 import android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class baslat extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  { 
 TextView yazi;
 TextView bir,iki;
 Button buton1,buton2;

 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 yazi=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 bir=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 iki=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
 buton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
 buton2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

 buton2.setOnTouchListener(this);

 buton1.setOnTouchListener(this);

 }
 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    yazi.setText(String.valueOf(event.getPointerCount()+"\n\n"));
            bir.setText(String.valueOf("Birinci "
 + (int)event.getX(0)+"\n\n"+(int)event.getY(0)));
        iki.setText(String.valueOf("Ikinci"+
 (int)event.getX(1)+"\n\n"+(int)event.getY(1)));
    //buton2.setLayoutParams(new
 LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
 (int)event.getX(0),
 (int)event.getY(0)));      return
 super.onTouchEvent(event);
            } @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    Button fds=(Button)v;


            return false; }


 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Old question but I was running my head in the wall with this problem until I finally came across just setting

```
android:splitMotionEvents="true"
```

on the layout view that contains the button views, which allows for multiple buttons to be pressed, which I found digging in the ApiDemos that are available in the sdk demos download

Answer (score 4):

In the Android UI framework, all touch events belong to the View where the touch originated. So if you touch your Button, all touch events are processed through that Button until you lift your finger up; this includes other touch pointers for multi-touch. In my experience the only way to achieve multi-touch across separate View objects (your 2 Buttons), is to capture all touch events in one View that covers the whole screen, and delegate the touch events yourself. It's a bit of work, but it can be done.

An example might be to include an ImageView that fills the screen but has no Drawable source (or it's completely transparent). Put this on top of your other elements (perhaps with a FrameLayout), and in the onTouchEvent() method of the ImageView, analyze the touch coordinates, and pass the touch event down to the correct button. This gets rather complicated with multiple touch pointers, but as far as I know, it's the only way to pass touch events to separate View objects.

Answer (score 3):

I was a little bored with this subject and i made an handler class for leading with multitouch buttons. Feel free to use and/or update that.

```
//CLASS TO HANDLE THE EVENT
    public class MultitouchButtonHandler {
            ArrayList<View> views_info = new ArrayList<View>();
            public MultitouchButtonHandlerResult onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent ev) {

            //GET EVENT INFO 
            final int action = ev.getAction();
            int action_masked = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            if(action_masked==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                return null;
            }

                //GET ABSOLUTE SIZE AND CHECK IF THIS ANY VIEW ATTACHED TO THIS POSITION
                final int original_location[] = { 0, 0 };
                v.getLocationOnScreen(original_location);
                final int actionPointerIndex = ev.getActionIndex();
                float rawX = (int) ev.getX(actionPointerIndex) + original_location[0];
                float rawY = (int) ev.getY(actionPointerIndex) + original_location[1];
                View eventView = getViewByLocation((int)rawX, (int)rawY);
                if(eventView==null) return null;

                MultitouchButtonHandlerResult result = new MultitouchButtonHandlerResult();
                result.view  = eventView;


                //CHECK WHAT KIND OF EVENT HAPPENED 
                switch (action_masked) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    result.event_type = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                    return result;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    result.event_type = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
                    return result;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                    result.event_type = MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL;
                    return result;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                    result.event_type = MotionEvent.ACTION_UP;
                    return result;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN: {
                    result.event_type = MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN;
                    return result;
                }

                default:

                break;

                }

                return null;
            }

            public void addMultiTouchView(View v){
                views_info.add(v);;
            }
            public void removeMultiTouchView(View v){
                views_info.remove(v);;
            }

            public View getViewByLocation(int x, int y){

                for(int key=0; key!= views_info.size(); key++){
                    View v = views_info.get(key);
                    //GET BUTTON ABSOLUTE POSITION ON SCREEN
                    int[] v_location = { 0, 0 };
                    v.getLocationOnScreen(v_location);

                    //FIND THE BOUNDS
                    Point min = new Point(v_location[0], v_location[1]);
                    Point max = new Point(min.x + v.getWidth(), min.y + v.getHeight());


                    if(x>=min.x && x<=max.x && y>=min.y && y<=max.y){
                        //Log.d("mylog", "***Found a view: " + v.getId());
                        return v;
                    }

                }

                //Log.d("mylog", "Searching: " + x +", " + y + " but not found!");

                return null;
            }

        }
```

```
//CLASS TO FULLFILL WITH RESULT
public class MultitouchButtonHandlerResult {
    public View view;
    public int event_type;
}
```

```
//In your view 
private OnTouchListener listener_touch_button = new OnTouchListener() {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      MultitouchButtonHandlerResult result=multitouch_handler.onTouchEvent(v, event);
     if(result==null) return true;

                switch(result.event_type){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        Log.d("mylog", "DOWN");
                break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        Log.d("mylog", "UP");
                break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            Log.d("mylog", "CANCEL");
                break;

                }

               Log.d("mylog", "View ID: " + result.view.getId());

               return false;
      }

 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this link -

How to use Multi-touch in Android 2
http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747

[How to code for multitouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229219/how-to-code-for-multitouch)

Comment: Continue reading: Part 2: Building the Touch Example >   http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-2-building-the-touch-example/1763

Comment: i did an multitouch example but it uses screen location..Thats means it work to whanr you click screen empty part..not button or somethink

Comment: İ got my answer:YOU CANT TOUCH 2 BUTTON İN SAME TİME..BUT YOU CAN TOUCH SCREEN AND YOU CAN RUN EACH BUTTON FUNCTİONS..AND YOU CAN DO İT WİTH BUTTON POSİTİONS...THANK YOU FOR ALL..