# Touch Multiple Buttons At The Same Time Android Development

Tags: android

I have an app in development that is a competition in the speed of clicking. But, i cannot press the 2 buttons at once.Which means that if one person holds his button down the other one cannot press his/hers. Please help!

Comment: Tried this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346148/android-work-multitouch-button

Comment: Tried it but i dont get some pieces

Comment: What you mean didn't get some pieces explain in more depth were you are stuck with

Comment: where to put
 private OnTouchListener listener_touch_button = new

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my phone did not support multitouch! :(