# how to handle multi touch on buttons

Tags: android, button, click, touch

I am making one sample android project dial pad so that if user presses any number I have to grab that value so that if user presses two buttons at a time how can I grab that two button values using touch event

Comment: try that: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: set seperate onClickListners for each button

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346148/android-work-multitouch-button

Answer (score 0):

See [Making Sense of Multitouch](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html), it is a really good article which helped me  a lot.

Basically you need override onTouch of your button like

```
private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

// The ‘active pointer’ is the one currently moving our object.
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

// Existing code ...

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    final int action = ev.getAction();
    switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        final float x = ev.getX();
        final float y = ev.getY();

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        // Save the ID of this pointer
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
        final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
        final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
        final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

        final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
        final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;

        mLastTouchX = x;
        mLastTouchY = y;

        invalidate();
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
        mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
        // Extract the index of the pointer that left the touch sensor
        final int pointerIndex = (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
        final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
        if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
            // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
            // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
            final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
            mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
            mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
        }
        break;
    }
    }

    return true;
}
```