# How to press two (or more) buttons at once

Tags: android, multi-touch

My app has 12 buttons with sounds, but only one button can be pressed at once. What do I need to do to enable multitouch in my app?

Here's some code of my Activity:

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    Button button1, button2, button3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);


    Button beatSound1 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    beatSound1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(beat2);
            Log.d("MY", "COW");
        }
    });
    Button beatSound2 = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    beatSound2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            playSound(beat3);
            Log.d("MY", "COW");
        }
    });
```

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14153741/2668136

Comment: Your `Activity` shows it implements `View.OnTouchListener` but you don't show any code for that and you are using `View.OnClickListener` for your buttons.

Comment: So how to set those buttons to View.OnClickListener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, as far as i can see, you're working with only one Thread. That's your problem, I  guess that your function `playSound()` is also in the same activity, you can't execute multiple calls of this function at once without multithreading (which can be done with `AsyncTask`).

Note that multitouching is not part of developers job, there is no way to enable more touching capability (this is part of hardware). But usually you can use 10~ fingers at once.