# Define key combination to perform an action in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In android, how can I define a key combination in app to perform some action?

For example, if user press `e` and `x` letters on a keyboard at the same time, how can I assign a special task to do when this event is fired?

Comment: can you elaborate your question a bit more bhawna

Comment: Do you mean that if user types 'e' and 'x' in EditText then it will show a dialog?

Comment: @Matteo he means if the user touches `e` & `x` at the same time, an event is fired

Answer (score 0):

You should know that any app you make will only capture 1 touch event at a time unless you utilize multi-touch. So first do this , [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/multi.html) , [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTouch/article.html) may help ,this was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346148/android-work-multitouch-button) before too.

Comment: it i s about touching multiple views but I want event of multiple keys to be pressed on keyboard.

Comment: I thought you are speaking about a game maybe, Please add more details in your post above, and mention the word 'keyboard'

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:}
return false;}
```

From this you would get the postion of yout touch.Now do some logic on setOnClickListner of other button or "x" here.

Hope it helps.